# Strange behavior of ping -I on Pi3

Tags: ping

Pi3 with static IP assigned to eth0 (192.168.0.164). Pinging loopback interface from eth0 using

```
ping -I eth0 -c 1 127.0.0.1
```

fails. However,

```
ping -I 192.168.0.164 -c 1 127.0.0.1
```

works. I cannot understand this.

Answer (score 1):

### Very Odd, But Normal?

I replicated this behavior on my RPi2B, which has a static address (192.168.1.111) on its eth0.

---

Oddly, `ping -I 192.168.1.111 -c 1 127.0.0.1` doesn't generate any `icmp` traffic on eth0; it only generates traffic on the local loopback:

```
pi@raspberry:~ $ sudo tcpdump -i lo -v
tcpdump: listening on lo, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
21:06:25.756416 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 26787, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    raspberry > localhost: ICMP echo request, id 6771, seq 1, length 64
21:06:25.757333 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 52634, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    localhost > raspberry: ICMP echo reply, id 6771, seq 1, length 64
```

On the other hand, `ping -I eth0 -c 1 127.0.0.1` doesn't generate any traffic on the local loopback; it just sends out an`icmp` message from eth0 and doesn't get any `icmp` messages back:

```
pi@raspberry:~ $ sudo tcpdump -i eth0 icmp -v
tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
21:06:00.740117 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 25587, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    raspberry > localhost: ICMP echo request, id 6733, seq 1, length 64
```

---

The networking wizards over at [serverfault](https://serverfault.com) might have more insight on this behavior.